# get only tag video from php

Tags: php, tags, preg-match

Hello I could help several days ago I am trying to make this code work.
I am trying to remove from an html the `<video>` tag that is inside a `<nonscript>`.

Example

```
<noscript>
        <video style="width:100%; height:100%;"
               controls="controls"
               autobuffer="autobuffer"
               class="player-html5"
               preload="metadata"
               poster="15.jpg">
            <source src="hello.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </noscript>
```

The code that I have is like this but does not return anything.

```
function vide($source){ 
    preg_match("'<noscript>(.*?)</noscript>'", $source, $match);
    if($match){ 
        return $match[1];
    }
}
```

Could you use the the dom document?

I just need everything found in the html video tag.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks

Comment: You actually should use DOM. And to make your regex work, you just need the `s` modifier.

Comment: dont work <noscript>(.*?)</noscript>/s

Comment: It does. `'~<noscript>(.*?)</noscript>~s'`

Comment: Excellent thanks!!

Comment: Using the dom document work fine too
function iframe($text) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    $doc->loadhtmlfile($text);

    $body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('noscript');
    if ( $body && 0<$body->length ) {
        $body = $body->item(0);
        echo $doc->savehtml($body);
    }
}